# cat can not open a file

Tags: bash, ksh

In a script (Say myScript.ksh) I have a variable which contains path to a file.

```
file=/home/vikas/input.ksh
```

in my code a need something from that file so I am doing a normal cat and grep on this file by doing something like this

```
myVariable=`cat $file | grep "on this line" | cut -d"'" -f2`
```

Now everytime I launch myScript.ksh, I get a error

```
cat: cannot open /home/vikas/input.ksh
```

But if I do same thing direcly on terminal I am able to see content of the file input.ksh

I dont know what I am doing wrong, can somebody please help me ?

Comment: Is it your file path? Have you tried /home/vikas/input.ksh?

Comment: "cat can not open a file" they don't have opposable thumbs, for one.

Comment: @vcsjones maybe i shouldn't, but plus one for the giggle-factor

Comment: Also, this seems like a superuser question

Comment: (semi-related comment) You can do away with `cat`, i.e. `grep "on this line" $file | ...`

Comment: Does your file use Unix or DOS line endings? That could explain why it works when you hardcode the file name in the script or set the variable from the command line.

Comment: can you put `set -o xtrace` at the top of your script and include the output in your question, I think that will tell us a lot. PS: This is turning into a help thread rather than Q&A. Maybe it is more relevant on on the ksh users list?

Comment: Check `ls -l /home/vikas/input.ksh`. Is it readable by everyone who runs the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah finally the problem solved, though I found the solution weired and could not understand why it worked. Actually I was reading this variable from some other file and it was something like this

```
file=$HOME/vikas/input.ksh
```

the problem was with $HOME what I did I removed $HOME from variable file and added that again by doing this

```
file=`echo $file | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/" } {$1=""; print $0}'`

file=$HOME$file
```

and after that I did the cat $file and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Try and flip your slashes, Linux uses `/` instead of `\`

Answer (score 3):

Use forward slashes, not backslashes

```
file=/home/vikas/input.ksh
```

Edit: OK, so that wasn't the problem.

Here's what we know at this point:

- He's using the correct slash.
- If he hardcodes the filename, the script works.
- Script is running as a different user (I think?).

Please indicate which user the script runs as, and post the output of:

```
ls -l /home/vikas/input.ksh
```

Also, what is the output of `file myScript.ksh`?

Comment: Sorry for typos, there were forward slashes only, as this variable is autogenerated by some process. I am not writing it manually in the script

Comment: if you hardcode the file name, does it work?  Is it something like a case sensitivity issue?

Comment: Also, you have copied and pasted the error message, right?  You didn't just retype it?

Comment: @vikasramnani: I can't help more without more info.

Comment: @vikasramnani You're sure there isnt some invisible characters in there somewhere?  How are you generating the variable?

Comment: yeah finally the problem solved, though I found the solution weired and could not understand why it worked. Actually I was reading this variable from some other file and it was something like this 

file=$HOME/vikas/input.ksh 

the problem was with $HOME what I did I removed $HOME from variable file and added that again by doing this 

file=`echo $file | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="/" } {$1=""; print $0}'`

file=$HOME$file 

and after that I did the cat $file and it worked